# Can't load image from saved URI in shared preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, uri

I let the user pick an image and save the URI I receive from this action in my shared preferences. This URI is used again in a different activity. This works fine for the one time the user picks the image and the URI is saved, but when the app is closed and opened again, the program just crashes when the activity tries to load the image of the URI saved in the shared preferences. Why is that happening, and why is it working the first time the image is chosen?

Here I make the user choose an image and save the received URI:

```
public void pickImage(View view) {
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");
        pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 1);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.putString(URI, uri.toString());
        edit.commit();
        }
    }
```

And here I load the image saved in the URI again:

```
   private void setImage() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String string_uri = prefs.getString(MainActivity.URI, "not found");

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(string_uri);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_card);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
```

Debugging showed the app crashes when it tries to open the InputStream. I checked it, and the URI used for that is always the same.

Comment: I generally use glide to load image saved in shared preferences

Comment: `the app crashes when it tries to open the InputStream`. Then you should catch other exceptions too. You have one catch block now. But if there is a catch you just continue with the code as if nothing has happened. Instead you should stop then. Display a toast to the user reporting e.getMessage() and return;

Comment: `the program just crashes when the activity tries to load the image of the URI saved in the shared preferences` AND `the app crashes when it tries to open the InputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

After extracting the URI from the sharedpreference, you can directly set the uri to the imageview, you don't need to convert it into a bitmap.

This is how you set the uri to the imageView:

```
    iv.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: Replacing my code with your line stops the app from crashing, but now the `ImageView` is just black and does not load a bitmap.

Comment: you don't need to convert into a bitmap, maybe the returned uri is blank or there's something wrong with the uri. The same way worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue in that saving process for the uri..

As you are saving

```
  edit.putString(URI, uri.toString());
```

It may take the uri as string..You can do one thing that..save the path from the uri..like

```
edit.putString(URI, uri.getPath());
```

everything else will remain same..
Hopes this works..